# Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no instance of 'XmlToolsFactory' registered

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, error-handling

I am trying run eclipse package drone. Then I got the following error. I am running package drone on top of jetty server. There is no issue in the package-drone product and I cannot findout the reason for the error. can anyone help me for this.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no instance of 'XmlToolsFactory' registered.
```

Comment: What version of eclipse? What version of package drone? Have you asked this question of the Package Drone devs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you experience this issue when running from inside the IDE, then the OSGi bundle `org.eclipse.packagedrone.repo.xml` is either missing or not started successfully.

On the OSGi console you can check with the command `ss org.eclipse.packagedrone.repo.xml` if bundle is active and running:

```
osgi> ss org.eclipse.packagedrone.repo.xml
"Framework is launched."

id  State       Bundle
180 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.packagedrone.repo.xml_1.0.0.qualifier
osgi>
```

`ACTIVE` tells you that the bundle is running. The number `180` is just the internal ID of the bundle and may be different.

If the bundle is not listed at all, then there may be an issue with the launch configuration. Check the launch configuration and ensure that the bundle is marked for startup. If the bundle is **not** in the `ACTIVE` state you can start if from the console with the command `start 180` (same internal ID as with the `ss` command). You can then check the launch configuration and ensure that the bundle is auto-started in the IDE.